# Change page transition on the same page

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition

I have a html with two internal pages (data-role="page"). One of the pages shows a days date and data which are connected to this date. When I swipe left or right the day should change.

What I need here is to get the page transition to show. It seems like I can't use the `$.mobile.changePage()` for the same page. Ultimately I don't want to refresh the page since I have some global variables I have to keep.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

EDIT:
Found the solution [Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2529). Used this line of code:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#reused-page", { allowSamePageTransition: true } );
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#other-page", { allowSamePageTransition:true } );
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been debugging for hours because of this. Why isn't this the default?!