# Links are not clickable on mobile site version (Wordpress + jQuery mobile)

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile

I run a website [raigle.com](http://raigle.com/), it has a mobile version (2012 theme used automatically when mobile is detected), spiced up with jQuery mobile. What is strange is that in mobile version you can't actually click some links in some cases.

When the site is loaded, you can click on the [Random link](http://raigle.com/random-link/) link, it will bring you a page with random item. But if you touch "try new one" link then, it will not work.

Lightboxes links with video are also broken. For example, if we go to site creation category, or any other, video goes to Youtube app rather then being shown in a lightbox. On a desktop video is always shown in a lightbox (I use Easy Fancybox plugin).

What can be a problem?

Comment: Could you show us some related code? What is the expected behavior? What have you tried?

Comment: So the code is in both cases like that:
<div vertical-align="middle">
  <img class="random-link-image" src="http://raigle.com/wp-content/gallery/general/random-link.png"> (<a href="http://raigle.com/random-link/">try new one</a>)
</div>. I think, it could be the problem of going going through the link to the current page - jQuery mobile might block it.

To check it, I placed second link to the start page, near the subject. And really leads to the start page, but leaves in the address bar the old address - raigle.com/random-link..

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like this on the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031564/change-page-transition-on-the-same-page

Comment: Derek, sorry it took me some time to find a way out. Actually, no hints on refresh in jQM helped me. One can click on a link which is other then current URL. So I created two identical pages with different URLs and send a user back and forth.